# password encryption using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a below java code for encrypting the password securely. But how do write the same code in Angular2. Can any one help to convert in to Angular 2.

```
public String encrypt(String input) throws PaySecureException {
            try {
                MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(Constants.SHA);
                messageDigest.update((input + Constants.SALT_STRING).getBytes());
                String encryptedInput = (new BigInteger(messageDigest.digest())).toString(Constants.PASSWORD_LENGTH);
                return encryptedInput;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new PaySecureException(Constants.NOT_AUTHENTICATED_ERROR_CODE);
            }
        } 
        public static final String SALT_STRING = "LongStringForExtraSecurity@#$!%^&*(*)1234567890";
        public static final String SHA = "SHA";
        public static final int PASSWORD_LENGTH = 16;
```

Comment: You shouldn't do this on client-side. It makes your code vulnerable to security hijacks.

Comment: Why not post your password via https back to your controller that just runs the code above and returns the encrypted value? Provide it as an api service.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a desperate need to do this on client-side, you can use [Crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js)

This library should help you create your needed password hashes, I've used it recently for simulating purposes, and I must say that I wasn't able to generate identical hashes for all the given methods and different variations of encoding that it supports, so I ended creating a simple Web Api that will do the hashing/crypting.

Usage:

```
require(["crypto-js"], function (CryptoJS) {
   console.log(CryptoJS.HmacSHA1("Message", "Key"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done using the following code

```
shajs('SHA1').update("LongStringForExtraSecurity@#$!%^&*(*)1234567890").digest('hex')
```